# jQuery - get value from input and then set them as style

Tags: jquery, css

I have some fields :

```
<div class="mystyle">
   <input name="font-size" value="12px" />
   <input name="font-family" value="Arial" />
   <input name="color" Value="#333" />

   <button class="setStyle">Save</button>
</div>
```

Please note I am not using a `form`.

Now When I click on button `.setStyle` then use `input` name as style attribute and value as attribute value, like:

```
font-size:12px;
font-family:Arial;
color:#333;
```

now assign this style to a div using `.css()`

Please tell me how do I do this properly with jQuery

**I have tried this:**

```
jQuery('.setStyle').click(function(){
    var parent = jQuery(this).parent('.mystyle');

   // now run each inside parent for geting name and value
   // run a loop for setting CSS, if value is empty dont add style
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing some jQuery script to do this? If so, please post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/V3y4J/

```
var $target = $('.target');
$('.setStyle').click(function(){
    $('.mystyle > input').each(function(){
        $target.css(this.name, this.value);
    });
});
```

If you want to improve performance (but then you shouldn't use jQuery), you can also use

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/V3y4J/2/

```
var $target = $('.target'),
    $inputs = $('.mystyle > input'),
    applyStyles = function(){
        $target.css(this.name, this.value);
    };
$('.setStyle').click(function(){
    $inputs.each(applyStyles);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$(".setStyle").click(function() {
    var attributes = $(this).siblings("input").map(function() {
        if (this.value != '') return this.name + "," + this.value
    }).get();

    for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
        $("#styleDiv").css(attributes[i].split(",")[0], attributes[i].split(",")[1]);
    }

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Za77A/3/

Comment: You should take the order of `<input>`s into consideration. If the markup changes, this would fail horribly.

Comment: @Dogbert -- Yes...yes this would. Give me a min, make this much better.

Comment: Thanks for answer and fiddle, But how to not add attribute name If input value is empty ?

Comment: @HowToPlease -- I would use Oriols answer below, it's cleaner, simply add the check in there for empty values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jQuery code :

```
$('.setStyle').click(function(){
    button = $(this)
    button.removeAttr('style')
    $('.mystyle input').each(function() {
        button.css({$(this).attr('name'): $(this).val()})
    })
})
```